# UITableViewCell creation on iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, allocation, autorelease

I am  creating an auto released  UITableViewCell in UITableView. When creating  more rows in a table it causes Memory allocation more.
I tried to allocate cell and release then and there. It produces Memory leaks.

Whats the solution to create UITableViewCell efficiently to avoid allocations and as well as leaks.

Comment: Please post your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath. Thanks!

Comment: [This article](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/) says all I wanted to say about `UITableViewCell` & its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reuse your UITableViewCell's:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```